# Extract coefficients for a formal power series using Lagrange Inversion Formula

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Given $f(x)$ is a formal power series that satisfies $f(0) = 0$

$(f(x))^{3} + 2(f(x))^{2} + f(x) - x = 0$

I know that the Lagrange inversion formula states given f(u) & $\varphi(u)$ are formal power series with respect to u, and $\varphi(0) = 1$ then the following is true.

$[x^{n}](f(u(x))) = \frac{1}{n}[u^{n-1}](f'(u)\varphi(u)^{n})$

How do I find the coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $f(x)$ using Lagrange inversion formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have

$$f(z)^3 + 2f(z)^2 + f(z) = z$$

and we seek $[z^n] f(z).$

While we wait  for a contribution from LIF experts  in the meantime we
can use  *Poor Man's Lagrange  Inversion* which is the  Cauchy Residue
Theorem. We have

$$[z^n] f(z)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} f(z) \; dz.$$

Now put $w=f(z)$ so that $w^3+2w^2+w = z$ and
$3w^2 + 4w + 1 \; dw = dz$ to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1} (1+w)^{2n+2}}
\times w \times (3w^2 + 4w + 1) \; dw.$$

Now $$w \times (3w^2 + 4w + 1) 
= 3 (1+w)^3 - 5 (1+w)^2 + 2 (w+1).$$

Extracting coefficients we thus have

$$3 (-1)^n {n+2n-2\choose n}
- 5 (-1)^n {n+2n-1\choose n}
+ 2 (-1)^n {n+2n\choose n}
\\ = (-1)^n \times
\left(3{3n-2\choose n}
- 5 {3n-1\choose n}
+ 2{3n\choose n}\right).$$

This is

$$(-1)^n {3n-2\choose n}
\left(3 - 5\frac{3n-1}{2n-1}
+ 2 \frac{(3n-1)3n}{(2n-1)2n}\right)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{1-2n} {3n-2\choose n}.$$

**Remark.**  The fact  that we  are given  $f(0) =  0$  determines the
choice of branch  so that $z=0$ corresponds to  $w=0$ (which is needed
when  we  make  the  substitution).   Also, if  we  choose  $\epsilon$
sufficiently  small  we  also get  a  small  circle  for $w$  (with  a
different $\epsilon.$)

**Addendum, five years later.** A better choice of integral
is

$$[z^n] f(z) = \frac{1}{n} [z^{n-1}] f'(z)
= \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z^n} f'(z) \; dz.$$

We put $w = f(z)$ and obtain

$$\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^n (1+w)^{2n}} \; dw
= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} {n-1+2n-1\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} {3n-2\choose n-1}.$$

Comment: This is the *back to the roots* variant! :-) (+1)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Can we apply the Cauchy Residue theorem to 2-dimensional Lagrange inversion problems? https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-88-7642-475-5_87

Answer (score 4):

Here we use a somewhat simpler but equivalent variant of the *[Lagrange Inversion Formula](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/magyar/Math880/Lagrange.pdf)*. (See Theorem A.2 in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick for the equivalence of the variants).

> **Lagrange Inversion Formula:**
>
> Let $g(x), f(x)\in x\mathbb{C}[x]$ be inverses: $g(f(x))=x$. If $g(x)=\frac{x}{\phi(x)}$ and 
>   $f(x)=x\phi\left(f(x)\right)$, then
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]f(x)=\frac{1}{n}\left[x^{n-1}\right]\left(\phi(x)\right)^n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

The functional relation
\begin{align*}
(f(x))^{3} + 2(f(x))^{2} + f(x) - x = 0
\end{align*}
can be written as $g\left(f(x)\right)=x$ with
\begin{align*}
g(x)&=x^3+2x^2+x\\
&=x(1+x)^2
\end{align*}

> We can write $$\phi(x)=\frac{x}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$
>
> and obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]f(x)&=\frac{1}{n}\left[x^{n-1}\right]\left(\phi(x)\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\left[x^{n-1}\right]\frac{1}{(1+x)^{2n}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\binom{-2n}{n-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\binom{3n-2}{n-1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the Lagrange Inversion Formula (1)
- In (3) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}

Comment: Nice work. (+1).